# Side effects of a iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, testing, side-effects, black-box

is there a way to measure side effects of a iphone app on other apps performance? at least using a black-box focus.

Any suggestion about a monitorization app with this orientation?

I have found that my app can know nothing about other apps, but I would like  to measure some kind of impact of my app on the rest of applications,  or in case it is not possible make estimations about  the overall system performance.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases your app will not run when another app is in foreground. There are only quite few reasons you are allowed to keep your app running in the background. If your app is one of these, Instruments gives you a great way to analyse performance not only on your app but on the hole device. Have a look into the WWDC2012 session 235 videos. It deals with app performance and analysis thru Instruments.